# Cannot get noise free realistic render in blender cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, image, noise-reduction

[image: render image 1]

I am a beginner modeler, trying to get realistic result. I have tried my best but i cannot remove the white spots from my scene in cycles. Lighting is not looking realistic. Please help me how can i do that i have also attached link below.

[**download file here**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B98j5WovC7PjcTlTYzR4V2xqajQ)

Comment: you missed the link... and thus we don't know what you linked... anyway, without knowing full rendering and lighting setup is impossible to give suggestions here..

Comment: @m.ardito The link was actually in there...just had to go searching :-)

Comment: yes, now I see there's a 55 (!) MB example file... too big for my mobile connection...

Comment: increase the size of your sun lamp. Suggested reading: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies/

Comment: The file is not avaible

Answer (score 3):

### 1. Read: [7 Ways to Get Rid of Fireflies Once and For All](https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/7-ways-get-rid-fireflies)

List of the techniques explained in the article:

1. Use Bigger Light Sources
2. Use Bigger Shadow Sizes
3. Use "Multiple Importance Sampling" for HDRs
4. Use 'Filter Glossy'
5. Check "No Caustics"
6. Use "Clamping"
7. More Samples

### 2. Read: [Using Portals to Accelerate your Render Times](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/using-portals-accelerate-render-times)

For an interior scene such as yours, Portals can make a big difference. Portals tell Blender to only channel the environment lighting through a specific area (like a window), which makes for faster, cleaner renders.

### 3. Learn about the new [Denoising](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/denoising.html) feature.

Grab the latest version of Blender (currently [2.79](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.79) Release Candidate 2). This includes the new Denoising feature, which works wonders. So after you have done Step 1 and optimized your settings, this is how you can really polish it all up.

※ Note that if Progressive Refine is enabled, Denoising options will be grayed out. [Learn more](https://developer.blender.org/T51712)